# Is $\frac{200^{200}}{199^{201}}<1$ or $>1 ?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Is
$$\frac{200^{200}}{199^{201}}<1\text{ or }>1 ?$$

My approach is if we consider the function $f(x)=x^ \frac{1}{x+1}$ then it is decreasing for $x>9$. So the answer is $<1$.

Comment: $ \frac{200^{200}}{199^{201}} = (1 + \frac{1}{199})^{199} \frac{200}{199 \cdot 199} \approx \frac{e}{199} << 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already know that the function $x \mapsto (1+1/x)^x$, $x>0$, is monotonically increasing to $e$ (so that, in particular, it is $< e$), then
$$
200^{200} = 200\cdot (199+1)^{199} = 200 \cdot 199^{199} \left(1+ \frac{1}{199}\right)^{199}
< \frac{200\cdot e}{199^2} \cdot 199^{201} < 199^{201}.
$$

Comment: Spectacular explanation.